React Use state run twice
I'm trying to run my Setup function once when the Discord Activity loads (https://discord.com/developers/docs/activities/how-activities-work).
My code somehow runs the function twice and creates an error.

Here is the code I'm using:
function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<authType>(null);

  async function setupDiscordSdk() {
    const CLIENT_ID = "my client id";
    const discordSdk = new DiscordSDK(CLIENT_ID, { disableConsoleLogOverride: true });
    await discordSdk.ready();
    console.warn('DISCORD SDK READY!') // This somehow calls twice

    // Authorize with Discord Client
    const { code } = await discordSdk.commands.authorize({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      response_type: "code",
      state: "",
      prompt: "none",
      scope: [
        "identify",
      ],
    });

    // Retrieve an access_token from your activity's server
    const response = await fetch("/api/token", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        code,
      }),
    });

    const { access_token, publicProfile, authkey } = await response.json();
    localStorage.setItem('bread:authkey', authkey);

    // Authenticate with Discord client (using the access_token)
    let auth = (await discordSdk.commands.authenticate({
      access_token,
    }) as authTypeNOTNULL);

    auth.publicProfile = publicProfile as boolean;
    auth.user.avatarURL = (auth.user.avatar ? `https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${auth.user.id}/${auth.user.avatar}.png?size=256` : `https://cdn.discordapp.com/embed/avatars/${(BigInt(auth.user.id) >> 22n) % 6n}.png`);
    auth.discordSdk = discordSdk;
    setAuth(auth);
    console.warn('AUTHED SUCCESSFULLY.');
  };

  async function openLink(url: string) {
    console.warn('Trying to open URL', url);
    console.log(auth)
    if (!auth) return console.error('Not authed');
    return await auth.discordSdk.commands.openExternalLink({ url });
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(auth), [auth]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setupDiscordSdk().catch(console.error);
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      ...
    </>
  )
}

export default App;

Everything else works, just that auth does not. Can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

in development mode react does a double render, as a way of catching errors like this.  would start by adding a flag that checks id auth is already in progress and consider you might not need the setupDiscordSdk method inside a use effect.

Outside a use effect it would execute at every re-render right? And I just tried, it also renders twice and produces an error

year if theres rerenders up at the App component level that'll not be te option for you, in that case you probably want to try the "auth in progress flag". Like the answer given below but you'll want to manually set a flag before the request starts not just check for auth complete as the other user suggested.

Build your app locally. This almost surely won't happen again, but React does this on purpose. They're trying to get you to catch errors like this now and not rely on timing that usually works. Once strict mode is removed in development mode it will only run once, but you should not remove strict mode for this purpose. Try creating a loading ref and setting it to true when you send the initial request, and then to false when the promise resolves, and check that ref before sending the request.

I am trying this with this code:
async function setupDiscordSdk() {
console.warn('Trying to login', isAuthing);
if (isAuthing) return;
setIsAuthing(true);
...
but it logs "trying to login - false" twice.. (isAuthing is a useState(false))

EDIT: added a useRef (didn't knew what it did lol) and it seems to work

I fixed it with the help of comments and by myself. Here is my updated code:
function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState<authType>(null);
  const [isAuthing, setIsAuthing] = useState(false);
  const [showLeaderboard, setShowLeaderboard] = useState(false);
  const hasInitialized = useRef(false);

  async function setupDiscordSdk() {
    console.warn('Trying to login');
    if (isAuthing) return;
    setIsAuthing(true);

    const CLIENT_ID = "1170963763340517466";
    const discordSdk = new DiscordSDK(CLIENT_ID, { disableConsoleLogOverride: true });
    await discordSdk.ready();
    console.warn('DISCORD SDK READY!')

    // ...

    setAuth(authing);
    console.warn('AUTHED SUCCESSFULLY.');
    setIsAuthing(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!hasInitialized.current) {
      setupDiscordSdk();
      hasInitialized.current = true;
    }
  }, []);


Just FYI using an "isMounted", "isInitialized", etc ref has been considered an anti-pattern for some time now. You are optimizing for a non-production "issue".

setupDiscordSdk function might be running twice due to React's StrictMode in development, which intentionally double-invokes certain lifecycle methods (including useEffect)
can you just add an if condition in your useEffect?
 useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth) setupDiscordSdk()
  }, [auth]);


That does not work neither, same issue: double render and error occurs.

the problem is that the request is being sent twice before completing. add a custom flag to your answer that toggles before the request starts and after the request completes and you'll have close to a right answer ;)

This might be a result of having StrictMode which causes it rerenders on production. If you want to get rid of this you can search your project for React.StrictMode,  you should find a syntax like this most likely in your index.js and remove that.
<React.StrictMode>
...
</React.StrictMode>


Removing StrictMode is basically never the answer nor correct. Just fix the problem in the code that StrictMode is exposing for you.
